# Как правильно можно узнать количество определенных символов в String/Integer'e?

Tags: java

Коллеги, вопрос такой:
Как правильно можно узнать количество определенных символов в String/Integer'e?
Допустим есть строка 1110001101011 - мне нужно из нее узнать кол-во единиц или нулей, как на Java это сделать? Стандартных методов нет...

Comment: Пройтись циклом, посчитать нули и единицы. В чем вопрос?

Comment: Просто удивительно, какой резонанс вызвала простейшая и похоже оторванная от реальной жизни задача.

Comment: Жду в ответах фабрику фабрик счетчиков символов )

Comment: Не накаркайте. А то можете получить фабрику фабрик счётчиков счётчиков символов.

Answer (score 8):

Наверное самый простой способ будет посимвольный разбор строки и сравнение каждого элемента отдельно, что-то вроде:

```
String str = "1100011";
int countNulls=0, countOnes = 0;
for (char element : str.toCharArray()){
    if (element == '0') countNulls++;
    if (element == '1') countOnes++;
}
```

Comment: Ну для 0 и 1 можно:

        int     cnt[] = {0, 0};
        for (char element: str.toCharArray()) cnt[element - '0']++;

Comment: Далее только оптимизация)
    String str = "1100011";
    int countNulls = 0
    for (char element : str.toCharArray()){
        if (element == '0') {
            countNulls++;
        }
    }
    int countOnes = str.length() - countNulls;

Answer (score 4):

[Регулярно не выражаться!](http://ideone.com/Lb4Y0)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String string = "1110001101011";

        Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        for ( int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++ ) {
            Integer n = map.get( string.charAt(i) );
            if ( n == null ) map.put( string.charAt(i), 1 );
            else map.put( string.charAt(i), ++n );
        }

        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если в строке только 0 и 1, то проверка в цикле выглядит некрасиво. Лучше сразу занести пары ("0", 0) и ("1", 0).

Comment: Согласен для частного случая, однако у меня общее решение и покормить придется всем basic multilingual plane, что совсем некошерно. Уж проще тогда сделать сахарный класс, который будет принимать null за 0.

Answer (score 3):

Если эффективно, то цикл. Если штатно - то есть готовый метод - [countMatches](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#countMatches(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)). Прям с демками. В общем случае лучше предпочитать готовые библиотечные функции, так как обычно они уже достаточно хорошо работают. И только если они не удовлетворяют по скорости/качеству (либо просто нет таких), тогда писать свой велосипед.

Но если это учебное задание, то тогда нужно писать так, как хочет преподаватель, и не важно, эффективно или нет, так как для некоторых преподавателей важно, что бы они понимали решение.

Но ещё я в условии заметил слово "Integer". Но в Integer'e нет символов (при желании их конечно можно найти там, например рассматривая Integer как 4 (или 2) char. Но это что то не то:)

Comment: У меня есть подозрение, что задача состоит в нахождении количества бит целого, равных 1. Просто автор не знает, что всего в Integer 32 бита.

Comment: Насчет штатного не совсем правда, это Apache Commons.

Comment: Apache Commons - это как boost для с++. Большая подборка хороших велосипедов.

Answer (score 2):

данное решение позволяет считать любые символы, у вас есть возможность самому задавать символы которые нужно посчитать. теоретически должно работать с приемлимой производительностью:

```
public class CountCharacters {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // two usage examples for provided input string
        countCharacters("1110001101011", '0', '1');
        countCharacters("1110001101011", new char[] {'0', '1'});

        // usage example for custom string 
        countCharacters("00112233445566778800qwertyuiop[]{}asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,./", 
                '0', '1', 'a', 'b', 'c');
    }

    private static void countCharacters(String inputString,
            char... interestedCharacters) {
        final int[] occurences = new int[256];
        final char[] array = inputString.toCharArray();
        for (final char c : array) {
            occurences[c] = occurences[c] + 1;
        }

        // dump results for characters you are interested in
        for (int i = 0; i < interestedCharacters.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("found '" + occurences[interestedCharacters[i]]
                    + "' occurences for character '" + interestedCharacters[i]
                    + "'");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

выводит в консоль:

```
found '5' occurences for character '0'
found '8' occurences for character '1'

found '5' occurences for character '0'
found '8' occurences for character '1'

found '4' occurences for character '0'
found '2' occurences for character '1'
found '1' occurences for character 'a'
found '1' occurences for character 'b'
found '1' occurences for character 'c'
```

p.s. минусы, - неоптимальное использование памяти + нет поддержки кодировок. в принцыпе последнее можно легко исправить

аналогичным образом работает решение для int'ов:

```
private static int[] ALL_DIGITS = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

protected static void countNumbers(int i) {
    countNumbers(i, ALL_DIGITS);
}

protected static void countNumbers(int value, int... digits) {
    // number consists of only 10 digits
    int[] occurences = new int[10];

    // copy value
    int x = value;
    while (x >= 10) {
        int low = x % 10;
        occurences[low] = occurences[low] + 1;
        x = (x - low) / 10;
    }
    occurences[x] = occurences[x] + 1;

    // dump results for digits you are interested in
    for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("found '" + occurences[digits[i]]
                + "' occurences for digit '" + digits[i]
                + "'");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

пример использования:

```
countNumbers(111000110, 0, 1);
countNumbers(1234567890);
```

результат:

```
found '4' occurences for digit '0'
found '5' occurences for digit '1'

found '1' occurences for digit '0'
found '1' occurences for digit '1'
found '1' occurences for digit '2'
found '1' occurences for digit '3'
found '1' occurences for digit '4'
found '1' occurences for digit '5'
found '1' occurences for digit '6'
found '1' occurences for digit '7'
found '1' occurences for digit '8'
found '1' occurences for digit '9'
```

Comment: Если учесть, что char-ы могут быть и китайские, то не великоват ли получается размер occurences [] ? (естественно 256 надо поправить).

Comment: что-то мне подсказывает что между этими фразами есть логическая связь
> нет поддержки кодировок
> char-ы могут быть и китайские

Comment: для большинства задач этого будет вполне достаточно

в том числе без русских букв.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class OneZero {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String s = "1011110011";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("1");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        int n = 0;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
            n++;
        }
        System.out.println("N = " + n);

    }

}
```

Выводит количество единиц в консоль

> `1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> N = 7`

Comment: Регэкспы для такой задачи - как-то жирновато. Да и объем кода больше.

Comment: Тем более, что регэксп и не делает здесь ничего.

Comment: Из серии: 

    Зачем просто, 
если можно сложно ?

Comment: @avp, этот девиз должен быть на хинди :-)

Comment: объясните чем жирноват то? можно выделить как отдельный метод и считывая с консоли входной параметр(символ) выводить сколько чего есть в строке\файле. Довольно просто и не объемно. Такое ощущение что Вас когда-то давно напугали reqexp'ами и вы теперь их боитесь до ужаса.

Comment: Тем что в простейшей задаче стоимость по времени возрастает в 4-5 раз. Неужели если на сегодняшний день аппаратная часть устройств позволяет не задумываться о скорости обработки и объемах используемой памяти, то нужно полностью этим пренебрегать?

Comment: этим способом можно найти в тексте сколь угодно огромное разнообразие конбинаций со всеми знаками алфовита и чисел, я дал такой пример, чтоб можно было смотреть с перспективой, ведь человек на одних "0" и "1" не остановиться, в реальных проектах это будет как раз то что нужно:-)

Comment: @Dex, будьте добры, привести какую-нибудь информацию о тяжеловестности операции pattern'a и matсher'a. Или просто объяснить почему он лучше цикла с использованием if\else.

Comment: @Dex,если посмотрите на исходники методов replaceFirst и replaceAll класса String, увидите там и pattern и matcher. Хотелось бы услышать конкретно неэффективность использование их для этой задачи, не прибегая ни к каким посылам в абстрактный поиск.

Comment: 2. Сложность функции от @Rams666 предсказуема всегда, она примерно равна одному циклу по всем элементам O(N). Ни больше ни меньше. В данном случае, я даже не возьмусь предсказывать какую сложность составляет паттерн и матчер.

Comment: 3 А еще мне интересно, как вы адаптируете этот код для `Integer` (вопрос включал это слово)? Будете конвертацией в строку заниматься?

Comment: 1 Вы время исполнения данной функции и функции с if/else сравнивали? Изначально выполнение данного кода занимает большее количество времени, чем код из поста @Rams666. А на рубеже от 1000 до 2000 символов в строке еще и расти начинает. Динамика сохраняется, примерно в пять раз этот алгоритм уступает в скорости.

Количество элементов в строке - 133330557
Время первого алгоритма - 820, второго - 4658
Количество единиц - 66668124